# Remove $watch from this directive

Tags: angularjs, optimization, angularjs-directive

I've wrote this directive to handle my date inputs: https://plnkr.co/edit/7hpc8u5pVc7iaNSwn7Zw?p=preview

```
app.directive('myDate', ['$filter', myDate]);  

function myDate($filter) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: template,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: link
    }

    return directive;

    function template(element, attrs) {
        var template = '<input ng-model="date" ng-keyup="keyup($event.keyCode)" ui-mask="99/99/9999" type="text" ';

        if (attrs.class) {
            template += 'class="' + attrs.class + '"';
            element.removeClass(attrs.class);
        }

        template += '/>';

        return template;
    }

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.keyup = function(key) { 
            if (key === 68) { // D key
                scope.date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'ddMMyyyy');
            }
        };

        ctrl.$formatters.push(function(data) { // model to view
            data = $filter('date')(data, 'ddMMyyyy');
            return data;
        });

        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(data) { // view to model
            var year = data.toString().substr(-4);
            var month = data.toString().substr(2, 2);
            var day = data.toString().substr(0, 2);
            var sep = '-';
            data = (year && month && day) ? Date.parse(year + sep + month + sep + day) : '';
            return data;
        });

        scope.$watch('date', function() {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.date);
        });

        ctrl.$render = function() {
            scope.date  = ctrl.$viewValue;
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I used $watch to keep my model updated... I would like to know if there is a better way to trigger $setViewValue(scope.date) without $watch; just to optimize it a bit.

Thank you!

Comment: why don´t you set the value on your keyup function?

Comment: I put `ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.date);` in the keyup function... but if it will change programmatically?

Comment: Well, depends on what programmatically change we are talking about

Comment: I think after an $http function...

Comment: At least changing $scope.test with a $timeout seems to work, but that´s because of the $render

Answer (score 0):

Add this to  your template:

```
ng-change="updateParent()"
```

And this to you link:

```
    scope.updateParent = function(){
      ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.date);
    }
```

Comment: mm... it seems from the doc that if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value it will not be triggered

Comment: I couldn't tell from your code that the date could change programmatically other than in scope.keyup.  So yes, you're correct ... ng-change will not fire from programmatic model changes.  One way or the other you'll need to kick off a digest cycle when the data changes programmatically.  So you can either cover all of your bases with the watch or handle input changes from the UI using ng-change and doing something like $scope.$apply() after programmatic changes.